# How can I run a regular task with user specified time and time zone?

Tags: postgresql

A regular job needs to be run for each of my users, but I'd like it to run when they're not on. Since they might be on at midnight, I'd like them to be able to specify a time as well as their time zone.

After running the job for a given user, I'd like to precompute the next occurrence of the time in their time zone and store it to make it easier to query (though I'm not certain this is the best way)

So far I've figured out the following:

- Since none of the date and time types store timezone, I need a separate field for timezone
- I need to store time without time zone so that it isn't converted while being operated on
- I (probably) can't use intervals because those don't account for daylight savings

I've figured out that using `AT TIME ZONE` on a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` will compute the absolute time for that time's occurrence of the local time, but I haven't figured out how to add in the user's local time preference.

So far I have this:
`SELECT (TIMESTAMP 'tomorrow' AT TIME ZONE timezone) my_table`

and I'd like to have something like this:
`UPDATE my_table SET next_day_start_timestamptz=((TIMESTAMP 'tomorrow' + day_start_time) AT TIME ZONE timezone) WHERE id=1` but I keep getting type errors.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is the data type of `day_start_time` and how it's stored.

If it's a text type and a proper integer or an integer type ( for eg: 09 or 9 ), you may simply do

```
select ((TIMESTAMP 'tomorrow'
   + INTERVAL '1 hour' * day_start_time::int) 
 AT TIME ZONE day_start_time ) FROM my_table;
```

If it's a time data type representing the start time, you may simply add it

```
select ((TIMESTAMP 'tomorrow'
       + day_start_time ) AT TIME ZONE day_start_time ) FROM t
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0cb8ecd11c22b0caca241227c1ad146f)